# Error implement pagination with Meteor-Pages

Tags: javascript, pagination, meteor

I am referring to the basic demo of Meteor-Pages.

Basic demo https://github.com/ianpogi5/meteor-pages/tree/master/examples/basic.

Meteor-pages https://atmospherejs.com/package/pages.

The idea is to create pagination and show 1 recommendations at each page.

Nothing shows up at the browser and I encountered these errors :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'pagesData' of undefined 

Exception from Deps recompute function: Error: Expected null or template in return value     
from inclusion function, found: [object Object]
```

My codes are :

pages.coffee

```
@Pages = new Meteor.Pagination 'Recommendations',
  perPage: 1
```

recommendations.coffee

```
@Recommendations = new Meteor.Collection("recommendations")
```

recommendations_list.html

```
<template name="recommendationsList">
 <h1>Recommendations for each user</h1>
  <div>
   {{#each recommendations}}
    {{> recommendationItem}}
   {{/each}}
  </div>

  {{> recommendations}}
</template>

<template name="recommendations">
 {{> pagesNav}}
 {{> pages}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved, there are two things that I have did wrong with the previous code. Below is the amended one.

recommendations.coffee

```
@Recommendations = new Meteor.Collection("recommendations")

// Pagination must put directly under the collections, because we want to run the 
// collection first before making the pagination

@Pages = new Meteor.Pagination Recommendations,
  perPage: 1
```

recommendations_list.html

```
<template name="recommendationsList">
 <h1>Recommendations for each user</h1>
  <div>
  {{> recommendations}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="recommendations">
 {{> pagesNav}}
 {{> pages}}
</template>
```